# ABRecordRef vCard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook, vcf-vcard

I would like to convert a `ABRecordRef` into an `vCard` or `NSData` to transmit it via Bluetooth. I've run into your question and I wonder if you were able to figure out how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Is very easy, I'm working with iOS 6 and I done with the following code:

```
ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[_ABRecordCards objectAtIndex:0];
ABRecordRef people[1];
people[0] = person;
CFArrayRef peopleArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)people, 1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
NSData *vCardData = CFBridgingRelease(ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(peopleArray));
NSString *vCard = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:vCardData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"vCard > %@", vCard);
```

I have a `NSArray` with `ABRecordRef` elements...

Comment: hello can you tell me how can i add all contact in one v card ?

Comment: yes this is possible and i have one Application and i have to do this after long time !!!

Comment: No need for temporary ABRecordRef array. You can just use    CFArrayRef peopleArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)&person, 1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);